Filtering azure devops release build based upon build tag with "Continuous deployment trigger"
I am adding a build tag using the below yaml powershell script. The final result will have a condition, but for testing purposes the condition was omitted. I am then trying to filter the release using the bottom picture. I have tried using "skip-release" with an exclude, and "-skip-release" with an include. Neither work. The release is always triggered.
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
      Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]skip-release" 


QUESTION: Do build tags actually work in the release filters? Or am I doing something wrong? I have searched for days, and asked both chatgpt and claude. No answers found yet.

It is not possible to specify build tags in Exclude filters. Why are you trying to use a tag with a minus prefix such as -skip-release? That's not the correct tag value.

@RuiJarimba chatgpt suggested it

TL;DR Excluding tags is not supported.
I suggest you try the opposite approach, i.e. add a tag to the builds you want to deploy and then configure the branch filters with an Include condition.
Example:

Notes:

All the filters specified here will be OR'ed, i.e., artifact matching at least one filter condition would be sufficient to trigger a release.
If you include multiple tags in the same line, they are AND-ed while evaluating the trigger condition, whereas if you include tags in separate lines, they are OR-ed.


Thanks I will try this. Side question. WHY is this not in the docs? (If it works)

@SpaceGhost440 click on the info icon on the right side of Build branch filters (see screenshot). I agree that the documentation on MS portal could be better.

TYVM! It worked! Once I added an artifact filter that I had added during testing everything worked perfectly.


it worked once I removed an artifact filter *

